# Did Adam name all the breeds of the same type of animal?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-bereishit, adam

[Breishit (Gen.) 2:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=62) indicates that Adam named all the animals.

Did he give each class of animals just general names, or was Adam specific to name each breed of animal as well? E.g. - Did he name them (of course, the equivalent in Hebrew) "Labrador retriever", "Basset hound" "Pit bull" for different dog breeds?

I am assuming that there were different breeds of animals from 
[Breishit 1:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) assuing that the word מינה means "kinds" or "type". Thus, it might imply that there were different types or "breeds" for each animal.

Comment: I would say that all the names we have today in Hebrew form - aryeh, lavi, gedi, keves - comes from Adam. But there is no reason to think that there were other Hebrew animal names that were forgotten by us.

Comment: Maybe he named each animal: Spot, Rover, Trevor, Scabbers, etc.

Comment: As in did he name 8 million species and their variations in one day, including all the animals that nobody in his day whatever know about or ever know what he named them? Is it even supposed to be literal history? As for breeds though, they're not actually distinct beyond how humans at any time choose to isolate them.

Comment: Dogs are kind of a bad example, since they started out as only one breed -  wolves that made themselves useful(helping hunt, protecting the living area, etc) in return for food scraps.  Mankind created the breeds later on than Adam.  Then again, his long lifespan would've given him plenty of time to develop a few different breeds.

Comment: Do we have proof that all those breeds were present in the Garden, and that they were not bred later from a common ancestor (ie, a wolf)?